# Custom sort of directory contents

Tags: python, sorting

I have a number of directories containing the files similar to the below example:

```
test
setup
adder
hello
_CONFIG
TEST2
```

The file(s) in these directories with the prefix `_` represent configuration files of significance. The aim was to have these files appear first when I listed the directory i.e. I would like to be provided with:

```
_CONFIG
TEST2
adder
hello
setup
test
```

However, I am using

```
for element in sorted(os.listdir(path)):
    print(element)
```

and this provides a list where files starting in uppercase are listed above the `_` prefixed files:

```
TEST2
_CONFIG
adder
hello
setup
test
```

Is there anyway around this without filtering each file by its first character and printing seperately as this would seem to be overkill.

Thank you

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sorted( ..., key = lambda s: ( not s.startswith( "_" ), s ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for element in sorted(os.listdir(path), key=lambda x:x.replace('_', ' ')):
    print(element)
```

Comment: Hacky: relies on the list not containing any strings starting with " ". This is not guaranteed, at least not on Windows.

Comment: @katrielalex: Not at all, it just makes _ equivalent to space while sorting, which kinda makes sense to me.

Comment: So, which file comes first: " foo" or "_foo"? Answer: the wrong one, according to the original question.

Comment: @katrielalex: The answer is "whichever was first in the original list", as python's sort is stable and the `key` makes them equal for sorting.